# Does itertools.product really generates all possible permutations?

Tags: python, permutation, product, python-itertools

This is probably a dumb question, but something just doesn't add up to me.

My code:

```
lowercase_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
combos = list(product(lowercase_letters_ascii, repeat=3))
```

This creates 15625 combinations. Isn't there supposed to be excatly 17576 (26^3) combinations?
What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: _"What am I missing?"_ The letter "j" :-)

Comment: Oh that's embarrassing. Thank you.

Comment: Note that Python has a [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behold!

```
>>> len(lowercase_letters)
25
>>> 25**3
15625
```

By eyeball, your list is missing the letter "j".